# Is there a way to ask questions specifically to SE managers?

Tags: feature-request, questions, deleted-questions, users

I have recently come across situations on this site that I would've liked to ask and bring up to SE managers/creators without it  being to the public or raising a flag. I specifically would like to have a conversation with the SE about a specific question/user that has been deleted. Is there some way I can do this? If not, can I make a request for all users to have the option/a way of contacting SE?

Answer (score 8):

The first order of business is to find if you want to contact [site moderators](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or [community managers](http://stackexchange.com/about/team#Community). These are disjoint groups of people: the former are volunteers, the latter are employees of Stack Something.

Moderators can be contacted using a flag, or you may be able to catch them in a chatroom. If you want to ask about a deleted question, it's more likely to be a question for moderators than for community managers.

Community managers can be contacted using the bold link **[contact us](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)** in the footer of every page.

That said, don't expect

> to have a conversation with the SE about a specific question/user that has been deleted

They don't have time for chatting in general, and do not disclose why a user was deleted for privacy reasons.

Comment: All of this. Moderators (and employees) can make a chat room private and can create one for you if necessary.

Comment: @AndrewLeach where do you click to have/ create a chat room

Comment: @anonymous See [How do I chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow) and its duplicate. There may be other answers too.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I understand that, but where may I find the chat room. I don't see anywhere where there would be an option to chat. I know I already got the privilege to chat because of my rank, but where may I go to find the chat room on the site?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Never mind I figured it out

Comment: @AndrewLeach How do I make my Chat room Private so the public can't gain access? Can you do that for me?

Comment: @anonymous Yes. If you invite the moderators to your chat room (so we can find it), any of us can do that. I can't find a room created by you in ELU, though. Inviting users is also covered in the MSE posts; unfortunately it may not be straightforward because chat user ids are not the same as site user ids.

Comment: @AndrewLeach done